# How can I tweak my kernel to use all CPUs in my rooted device?

Tags: custom-roms, huawei, kernel, cpu

I have Huawei ALE-L21 alice (2015) `Magisk`-rooted `Bootloader`-Unlocked `Xposed`-Installed but it's somehow slower and I decided to tweak my CPU but here is what `ES Kernel Manager` shows:

[image]

Also, I can't actually use the governor

[image]

This is my ROM info:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure that is just how big.LITTLE architechture works, you either have the big cores active or the little cores active, you can't have all 8 of them active at the same time.  Also, if you're maxing your CPU settings, you're defeating the entire purpose of the kernel's governer and will drain the battery quite rapidly. Also, your CPU options will depend entirely on what the kernel allows for, so you may want to reach out to the kernel development team for the ROM you are using, which is likely the Viper ROM maintainer for your device.

Comment: So, I can't just flash another kernel on-top?

Comment: Not to get all 8 cores working at once... That just isn't how big.LITTLE architecture works in general, the little cores handle the simple and background tasks when there is nothing going on to save battery, and the big cores take over when your actively doing stuff that takes some power... This is handled by the kernel's governer and I/O scheduler. You might find a kernel with a different governer or I/O scheduler, but you likely won't fine one that can get all 8 cores to work at once, plus most apps can't use more than 1 or 2 cores, they are not designed to.

Comment: What is the problem your trying to fix?

Comment: The problem is related to speed. There is so much latency on this device and Maybe, it is increasing as mush as I install more apps in internal but I have adopted storage.

Comment: Or maybe it is because of the RAM as  I only see less than 500MB each time I go to recent.

Comment: Adopted storage is always slower than native storage... I wouldn't sorry about the RAM, you have 2GB which is sufficient and the kernel will manage it. If you have 500MB or so free all the time, you don't have memory issue (free ram is wasted ram). The problem here is you have a 5 year old device and it just doesn't have the resources for modern android apps. Unlike computers, phones and their hardware have a much faster use cycle, typically 2 years (low end hardware) to 4-5 years (high end hardware) is their legitimate useful life.

Comment: Not to say you can't use them today... But they will be slow and laggy at times as they just don't have resources of a Pixel 4 or Samsung S11 or similar device which is the target platform for today's development. Phones are quite optimized when released, in general kernel updates, governors, clock setting, etc, will not give you massive changes in performance, but smaller ones that are sometimes noticeable and sometimes not. Eventually, you need to accept that a piece of hardware just isn't sufficient for your needs, and accept that mobile hardware has a much shorter life.

Comment: Oh man, that hurts. Anyway I did a lot of effort for this phone to be in this state. It's much better than stock state! 
Btw, What is the best recent Android smartphone that can be rooted easily that you may suggest for me to buy?

Comment: The only phones I've used for a several years... Google Pixels.. The Pixel 4A is an excellent device at double it's price. We have two of them and tehy are excellent. My 2 cents worth.